# Why doesn’t the SLS have a service structure?

Tags: saturn-v, launchpad, sls

Both the Saturn V and the Shuttle had the Mobile Service Structure and the Rotating Service Structure respectively for work on the pad. Why doesn’t the SLS have such a thing?

Comment: If they did, they probably wouldn't have to roll back to the VAB to change the batteries on the range safety system with all the schedule implications of that. https://blogs.nasa.gov/artemis/2022/09/03/nasa-to-stand-down-on-artemis-i-launch-attempts-in-early-september-reviewing-options/ So this is a very timely question indeed.